# Retrieving Dynamic TextViews on screen rotation

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I have been using *onSavedInstance* and *onRestoreInstance* for saving the variables during a change in the screen orientation. But in the case of **dynamic textViews** , it is difficult to retrieve the values and populate them in their corresponding layouts. Does Android provide any in-built function to save d text of dynamic views?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
           In your XML layout file , use `android:id="@+id/edittext1"`. What I do, is deal with the configuration changes myself. It reduces the "lag" that your app would encounter while changing orientation.

Comment: I have used the View id's like the way you have mentioned and _Reducing the lag_ has nothing to with the screen orientation changes i guess.